# What is the best way to sort an array of TIME in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, date

I have an array of time like this `Date[] arrival = new Date[n]` how to sort them in ascending order without using inbuilt Array.sort methods.

```
public static void sortArrival(Date[] arrival,int len) throws NullPointerException
{
    for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<len-1;j++)
        {
            if(arrival[j].before(arrival[j+1]))
            {
                System.out.println("sorting dates..");
                Date t = new Date();
                t = arrival[j];
                arrival[j] = arrival[j+1];
                arrival[j+1]=t;

            }
        }
    }
```

However this method throws an null pointer exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Date Class already has a compareTo function built into it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

If you pick a sorting algorithm you should be able to just use the compare to in the algorithm.

An insertion sort for example:

```
for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
    Date toInsert=arr[i];
    int j=i;
    while(j>0 && toInsert.compareTo(arr[j-1])<0) {
        arr[j]=arr[j-1];
        j--;
    }
    arr[j]=toInsert;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be throwing a `NullPointerException` because of the `len` being provided might be greater than actual array length. You can just get the length of `Date` array using `.length`.

```
public static void sortArrival(Date[] arrival) throws NullPointerException {
  int len = arrival.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner method would be as follows.

Create a new `Comparator<Date>`, and use `Arrays.sort(arrival, COMPARATOR_DATE);`. By using a comparator, this enables you to take advantage of Java's built in array-sorting function.

You could create the `COMPARATOR_DATE` object as follows:

```
public static final Comparator<Date> COMPARATOR_DATE = new Comparator<Date>() {
     @Override public final int compareTo(final Date pDateA, final Date pDateB) {
          return pDateA.compareTo(pDateB);
     }
};
```

It's this object that Java uses to compare each individual element whilst sorting the array.